# How to assign both client-side javascript function and server side function to a dynamically added control in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Assume we have control textbox which is dynamically created (eg. date picker) 
Based on the date selected its needs to be validated using client side javascript function
and on the same date selected it should be  serving as input for server-side function to compute the value in other dynamic cell. Can there be conflict between both events?

Comment: I don't see any problems with having both client-side and server-side events and can't think of any "conflict". Could you possibly expand your question with more details on your specific requirements?

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Yes, I tested the code and it is possible my code was             Textbox tb = new TextBox();                                             // Set a unique ID for each TextBox added
 tb.ID = "TextBox_dynamic";
 //dynamically assigned javascript function //showdate      tb.Attributes.Add("onChange", "return showdate(this)");   //dynamically assigned server side function                      tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tb_TextChanged);                  and this worked :-)